# Why can't I move to another view Controller ? using tab bar and googleSignIn? Using UItabBarController and UIViewController and NavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I build an app using xcode 8 - swift 3. Here is a screenshot of my storyboard first , then I will explain the issue since I used numbering for further clarification.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuvAT.jpg

Three navigation controller and a view controller are connected directly with a tabBarController ( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ) as in the attached image. Two other view controllers are accessible from the (1a) view controller. (1a) view Controller is a signup view using only google signup, which has a googleSignIn button. If sign in success then a perform segue function will be called to show (1b) view controller.

Before adding the tab bar and the navigation controller everything was great and working smoothly but after adding them when it comes to perform the segue.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I did try breakpoints and debugging but could not find the nil and optional value error, is it in 1a or in 1b.

I wish the issue is clear and I hope for an answer soon.

thanks for your help,

Comment: Set  an exception breakpoint.  Show the code where the nil object exception occurs

Comment: did that found out that there is a connection I did not remove when I deleted a view

Answer (score 0):

How are you performing the segue? Notice that if you want to properly perform a segue from 1a to 2a, you have to make a segue from 1a to the navigation controller of 2a. I don't currently see a segue from 1a to 2a on your storyboard image so if you do that it should work :)

Comment: Sorry @akbapu , i meant the segue from 1a to 1b , not 2a that was a mistake.